# error command gcc failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, xcode, macos, gcc

I am having trouble installing `gcc`. Apparently I need gcc 4.0 in order to install a python package.
it gives the error of :

```
error: Command "gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc 
-arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 
-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include 
-Ibuild/src.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7 
-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include 
-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 
-c build/src.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/src/_pycambmodule.c 
-o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/src/_pycambmodule.o"
     failed with exit status 1
```

I have both gcc and gcc 4.0 in `/usr/bin` but I dont know why its not working.
It also gives the error  `gcc failed with exit status 1`.
Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The command it's running says `-arch ppc -arch i386` and I don't think that is valid for GCC 4.0 (it can't create an executable for both ppc and x86).

Are you *sure* you need GCC 4.0, not 4.0 or a later version?  4.0 is very old, so any package that doesn't work with newer versions of GCC is probably quite broken and unmaintained.